# Valence API Application XXX is trying to access your information.

Tags: desire2learn

This there a way to remove this check, when a user first accesses my Valence application??

> Application xxx by xxx is trying to access your information. Would you like to proceed?
>   Do not ask me again for this application

Do not ask me again for this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove this check. This is an important change in order to be able to have an app that appears just like the rest of the tools and I know it is being tracked for a future release.

Comment: Thanks, thought that might be the answer, but wanted to check any way.